# Marking a select control option as selected preventing the default value to be shown jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple HTML select with options. What I do is - set an option of that control as selected just after the page is loaded. My question is - how can I do that so the users won't see the first option of the select and will see the select with the value from the DB set. Here's the example:

```
<select id="simpleSelect">
   <option value = "1">One</option>
   <option value = "2">Two</option>
   <option value = "3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Setting the value as follows:

```
$("#simpleSElect").val(2);
```

Now the users will see the select with selected option "One" and it will flash changing the option to "Two" once the jQuery code is executed. This flashing does not look good and I'm curious if there's a way to prevent this flashing and show the users the select with directly "Two" selected.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you adding the option to select element.

Comment: It's being added dynamically. The data comes from the DB. When I add the values to the select I don't know which value is going to be selected afterwards.

Comment: you can set value while adding options to the select box by setting `selected` attribute to option

Comment: I can't do that. The select is being populated by a different web service than the function which sets the value.

Comment: can you make select box hidden when it loads and then select a value and make it show.